# Matrix Notation: <mat>, what is it useful for?

Tags: matrices, notation, vectors

I have a 2 dimensional squared matrix: $Im \in \mathbb{R}^{c \times c}$ with $c$ a fixed integer.

What is the difference with refering to $\langle Im\rangle$ and *just* $Im$ ?

I found this notation in a research paper. It makes sense when refering to the following situation $\langle x, y\rangle = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{x_i y_i}$ , but what's the benefit to use it when there is only one matrix inside the notation ?

Research Paper cited (Page 4): https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05921

Extract of the article with the target of my question in bold:

> We are given a set of $M$ medical images $\mathbf{I}_m$ showing healthy anatomy, with $m=1,2,\dots ,M$, where $\mathbf{I}_m \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times b}$ is an intensity image of size $a \times b$. From each image $\mathbf{I}_m$, we extract $K$ 2D image patches $x_{k,m}$ of size $c \times c$ from randomly sampled positions resulting in data $\mathbf{x}=x_{k,m} \in \mathcal{X}$, with $k=1,2,\dots ,K$. **During training we are only given $\langle \mathbf{I}_m \rangle$** and train a generative adversarial model to learn the manifold $\mathcal{X}$ (blue region in Figure~2(b)), which represents the variability of the training images, in an unsupervised fashion. For testing, we are given $\langle \mathbf{y}_n, l_n\rangle$, where $\mathbf{y}_n$ are unseen images of size $c \times c$ extracted from new testing data $\mathbf{J}$ and $l_n \in \{0,1\}$ is an array of binary image-wise ground-truth labels, with $n=1,2,\dots ,N$. These labels are only given during testing, to evaluate the anomaly detection performance based on a given pathology.

**Secondary question:** Does it have any sense to talk about $\langle \mathbf{y}_n, l_n\rangle$ in this scenario ? Because it can't represent an inner-product ...

Comment: Use `$\langle$` and `$\rangle$` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$, respectively.

Comment: Post edited with your recommendations. Thanks

Comment: Just “a research paper” is a rather useless reference! Please tell us *which* paper (preferably with a link to it as well) if you want a better chance of getting a meaningful answer.

Comment: @HansLundmark I have updated my post with a full quote. I hope it will be precise enough

Comment: Much better now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This indeed has nothing to do with inner products.

It seems to me that they are using $\langle \mathbf{I}_m \rangle$ for the set
$$
\{ \mathbf{I}_1,\dots,\mathbf{I}_M \}
,
$$
or maybe more likely the vector (or $M$-tuple)
$$
( \mathbf{I}_1,\dots,\mathbf{I}_M )
,
$$
which might perhaps also be written as
$$
\langle \mathbf{I}_1,\dots,\mathbf{I}_M \rangle
$$
by some people.

And $\langle \mathbf{y}_n, l_n \rangle$ would then be $N$-tuple of pairs
$$
\bigl( (\mathbf{y}_1, l_1),\dots,(\mathbf{y}_N, l_N) \bigr)
.
$$

Comment: Do you think the way these sets were written in the article is valid ? Or is it incorrect from your point of view ?

Thanks a lot for your answer @HansLundmark, I wait for your answer and validate your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by “valid”? We can use whatever notation we want, as long as we define it. In this case, it seems the authors come from a context (computer science? machine learning? image processing?) where the angle bracket notation is sufficiently standard that they don't even feel the need to explain it. But to me (trained as a mathematician), it feels a bit unfamiliar.

Comment: They come from NeuroImagery and Machine/Deep Learning, however the notation is not at all defined anywhere in the article and I have never seen such a notation anywhere... Do you think it is worth notifying the original author ?

Comment: I wouldn't bother. Apparently, the authors must have seen this notation been used many times, otherwise they would surely have explained it.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help.